Push-pull BJT configuration can't pull output to ground fully
I'm designing a circuit to mix multiple audio signals generated by a MCU. There are some pulse signals generated with timers as well as a few custom waveform signals generated with DACs. The signals vary between 3V VDD and ground. To simulate the circuit, I modeled the individual signals with power supplies in KiCAD (VDD is also visible here):

I want to control the volume (what's a better phrase for this?) of the pulse signals using PWM with low-pass filters to generate a voltage level to be pulsed using the pulse signals, so I added a couple of BJTs in push-pull configuration for every pulse signal:

Here's the PWM signals for reference. They're also modeled as pulse power supplies:

All signals are then mixed with a resistor network and hooked into a voltage buffer to drive a load which is going to be an electromagnetic buzzer or small earphone speakers in the real circuit:

The issue I encountered is that the PNP BJTs seem to be unable to pull the P1-4 lines all the way (or close enough) to ground, which I'm guessing is because of the voltage drop between emitter and base. You can notice the voltage dips below the 0.7V point only when all signals go below that point. This causes the signal to "bend" at the 0.6ms point rather than following the sine wave smoothly:

(VP1-4 are blue, green, yellow and red respectively. VW1 is pink and VMIX/VLOAD are orange)
I don't have a negative voltage source in my circuit to pull the base lower than ground. What else can I do? Or is there an option better than push-pull transistors?

Would digital potentiometer be fast enough here?

@Jens the signals are not going to exceed 20kHz since they're audio signals so it should be fine I think. Any specific parts I should check? I'm trying to use as many common and cheap components as possible.

Why do you need the transistors at all? Can't you modulate the signal directly? You're also feeding the signals into a high-Z load.

If you have many channels, digital potentiometers with I2C interface would be problematic, so you would need some with SPI interface. Is 80 ct per channel expensive here?

@MOSFET modulate the signal directly how?

@Jens it's getting on the expensive side. 4 channels would be more expensive than the MCU itself (some STM32 or CH32 likely)

"I want to control the volume (what's a better phrase for this?" Amplitude.

@Tooniis "I'm designing a circuit to mix multiple audio signals generated by a MCU". Why not perform the modulation on the upstream MCU's locally? In other words, why do this post processing when you could do it at the source? Use the final amplifier as the master mixer. Or you're not describing your problem completely...

Are you sure you want pull to Gnd instead of high impedance?
If the Gnd is true you can use a common emitter. When you use a Rc=1k and 100k to mixer the error should be less than 1%. At plus 3V the Rc makes error about 30mV (3V*1k/100k) and at Gnd the Vce_sat makes also ~30mV.
Another words the design can be very close to symetric.

Btw, this kind of stuff are better to do with symetrical supply and modulate the signal around Gnd. Then you can use analog switches like 4066be.

You can't get below 0.7 with devices that way. Exchange the NPN and PNP; put 2 10k in series between the bases and drive the midpoint.
That'll get to about 0.1 V. For lower use mosfets - one CD4007 will get you 3 of the channels.
